# Rails multi tenant app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I'm creating a multi tenant app that something like project management software.

In my structure, there is a **User** table that excluded from multi tenant.

User comes my sign-up page, fills the subdomain field called Company then I create a schema for this user. So, they can access their account as *companyname.example.com*. Everything is okay so far.

I also have an **Account** table to store subdomains with a creator user.

Now, I also created a table for Account permissions. This table includes Account_id and user_id. I did something like that because, user could join more than one Company with same email address.

Conclusion;

- User table
- Account table
- Account_permissions (to check when someone try to login to specific company. Because, they have more then one company.)

Does this make sense ? Do you have any idea in this case ?

Comment: the structure you showed has a lot of sense, I'll recommend you the gem apartment https://github.com/influitive/apartment to separate the data by schema for tenant (using postgres)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. However, I'm already working with it. I just need to get feedback for my structure.